# Why does the return value in function f return the display function instead of x value

Tags: javascript

hi a would like to ask why this code returns a function and not the x value.
Thanks in advance.

```
function f() {
  function makeClosure(x) {

    return function(){
      return x;
    };
  }
  var a = [];
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a[i] = makeClosure(i);
  }
  return a;
}
var a = f();
console.log(a[0]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makeClosure` is returning functions, so your array `a` is filled with functions.

`a[0]` will return the function, `a[0]()` will return x

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `makeClosure` you will see that it returns a function that in turns returns `x`.

Within the loop `a[i] = makeClosure(i);` assigns the function returned by `makeClosure(i)` in the array at the `i` index.

Running a function at a specific index in the array will return the related `x` value.

`a[0]();` should return `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Function `f()` returns an **array**.

So `var a=f()` assigns an array in `a`.

Now each array element is itself a **function**. So if you access any array element in the array `a` it will simply access the **function definition** but will ***not execute it***.

Hence to execute the function you need to call the array elements as a function i.e. in place of `a[0]` in `console.log(a[0]);` you need to use `console.log(a[0]());`

### This was the only reason...